# Creating a list from user input using a for loop

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, python-2.7, numpy

I am trying to make loop in python where the user input an array 5 times and store them for each i from 1 to 5 in a[i],but my code didn't work.Here is my code :

```
import numpy
from numpy import linalg
import numpy as np
for i in range(5):
    u[i]=np.array(input(" "))
    print u[i]
```

Comment: First off, remove the superfluous first two lines...

Comment: Like @TimPietzcker said, you need to remove those two lines: they're nor only superflous, but they clutter up the namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to tell Python that `u` is going to be a list. Otherwise `u[i]` will throw a `NameError` because you're trying to access `u` without having defined it.

Then, you need to grow the list dynamically, otherwise `u[i]` will throw an `IndexError` because, again, you're trying to reference `u[i]` before it has been created.

```
import numpy as np
u = []
for i in range(5):
    u.append(np.array(input(" ")))
    print u[i]
```

Comment: The `print u[i]` is probably not part of the code (I'm guessing it's debugging) so you could suggest a list comp

Comment: @jamylak: Perhaps, but that might be too advanced a construct for someone with an unsure grasp of basic Python concepts.